# How to access a file from one bucket to another in AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I can access a file from one bucket to another bucket in AWS with cloudfront_url. But I want to use bucket name instead of cloudfront_url.

How can I access the file using bucket name or without cloudfront_url ?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use the s3 endpoint to access the other bucket file.

Could you please elaborate the scenario for providing an appropriate solution.